# reading json files from s3 to glue pyspark with glueContext.read.json gives wrong result

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Does anyone know why `glueContext.read.json` gives me a wrong result?
Basically the below 2 methods give me very different results. After exploding, `df2` has much fewer records than `df1`.
anyone had experienced the same?
Thanks!!

```
df1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", format="json", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://.../"]})


df2 = glueContext.read.json("s3://.../",multiLine=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options` is used to read files in groups from source location (large files), so by default it considers all the partitions of files. Below is the syntax:

`df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", {'paths': ["s3://s3path/"], 'recurse':True, 'groupFiles': 'inPartition', 'groupSize': '1048576'}, format="json")`

Here `groupSize` is customisable and you can change it according to your need.

Meanwhile `glueContext.read.json` is generally used to read specific file at a location.

So in your case it might be happening that the `glueContext.read.json` is missing some of the partitions of the data while reading. This is the reason that there is difference in size and rows in both the data frames.

Comment: Thank you . originally I chose to use glueContext.read.json is because it "seemed" working as I have tons of buckets/groups to read. For example , if I  want to read in all json files in this path "s3://.../year=2019/month=11/day=06/" how do i do it with  glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options ?

Comment: I had to list every single sub buckets ,I feel there should be a better way. for example: I had to do this - df0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", format="json", connection_options = {"paths": [ "s3://.../journeys/year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=12/" ,"s3://.../journeys/year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=13/" ,"s3://.../journeys/year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=14/" ,"s3://.../journeys/year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=15/" ,"s3://.../journeys/year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=16/" ....]})

Comment: let me add that if I do glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", format="json", connection_options = {"paths": [ "s3://.../year=2019/month=11/day=06/" ]}) , it won't work.